# How to add a form inside a specific layout?

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I am not that PRO using WindowsForms because I do not use them too much but right now I am developing a Inventory system so this is my approach(design):

[image]

I have used 3 ***FlowLayoutPanels***, I am trying to show various Forms inside *FlowLayoutPanel3* when clicking specific button in the left panel the flowlayoutpanel3 will show/trigger the specific form.

**What I have tried?**, well I have read that I can use ***MDI container*** and stuff like that but I noticed that it is a different approach because I do not want to show a separate window, just just inside the flowlayoutpanel3 and maximized.

I have been googling solutions but could not find a solution. *** OR is there any item in the toolbox to perform this kind of stuff?***

PD: I am using VS2019 and C#.

Comment: in which language?

Comment: I have updated it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the new form, set it's `TopLevel` to false, add it to the panel controls and maximize it:

```
var frm = new Form(); //Or whatever form type you want to use.
frm.TopLevel = false;
frm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
flowLayoutPanel3.Controls.Add(frm);
frm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
```

You may need also to make it visible

```
frm.Visible = true;
```